# What are different encoding schemes used in gigabit ethernet?

Tags: digital-communications, modulation, channelcoding, communication-standard, multiplexing

I was reading about digital transmission, there are many steps namely

1. Analog to Digital conversion
2. Source coding
3. Channel coding
4. Line coding
5. Pulse shaping
6. Modulation
7. Multiple access techniques

Out of curiosity, I tried to find information about what are the techniques used in ethernet (standard Gigabit) for 2nd to 7th, I was able to find the technique for 7th and 3rd but was unable to find any information about any other points. Can someone help me with it?